# Filtering algorithm working on one machine but not on other

Tags: python, matplotlib, filtering

I have a certain filtering routine

```py
import scipy as sp
def remove_wiggles(x, y, p):
    """ Wiggle removing routine. Idea is to interpolate between the points in which the   
    curvature goes to 0 to obtain the trend of the oscillation """

    # Interpolate the given curve (x, y)
    # The trend of the curve should be where the curvature of the signal goes to 0
    fwiggle = sp.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(
        x,
        y,
        k=3,
        s=0
    )
    # fwiggle is a cubic spline.
    # derivs is an array which contains the 3 derivatives (0, 1 and 2 order) at each point of x
    derivs = np.array(
        [fwiggle.derivatives(_k) for _k in x]
    ).T
    # Get and interpolate the second derivative
    d2 = sp.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x,
        derivs[2],
        k=3,
        s=1.0
    )

    wzeros = d2.roots()
    wtrend = sp.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(
        wzeros,
        fwiggle(wzeros),
        k=3,
        s=0
    )

    return wtrend(x)
```

which works perfectly fine on the tests I run on my laptop. However, when I try to use this filtering method on the cluster, I get the following error `dfitpack.error: (m>k) failed for hidden m: fpcurf0:m=2`, with the signal `y` being exactly the same.

I used this filtering for a past project, and encountered the same problem. Luckily I did not **need** to use the cluster to filter this. However for my present project filtering needs to be applied each time a new signal is generated and for that I need the cluster.

Seems to be a problem of the cluster on how it calculates the interpolation. For example, for the case of the `y`'s I am using right now, in my laptop it yields a (correct) filtering and the `wzeros` array (the points where the signal crosses the trend line, the one we are interested in) has a `len()` in the order of the hundreds, while in the cluster it just has 2 elements (which is what raises the error).

## For reference

[unfiltered signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZB5O.png)

[and the filtered signal by my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHDoS.png)

The red line you can ignore, it is just the second integral of this curve.